# OxyPlot.Wpf integer axis - no MinimumMajorStep property

Tags: oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot.Wpf and have a need for an axis that will only show integer major steps.
`OxyPlot.Wpf.Axis` does not have a `MinimumMajorStep` (which `OxyPlot.Axis` has). Is there a simple way to achieve the required objective?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
`OxyPlot.Wpf.Axis` has a public member `InternalAxis`, which is a `OxyPlot.Axis` so all I had to do is add the following code somewhere appropriate:

```
axis.InternalAxis.MinimumMajorStep = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understood your question correctly. You could make use of the `MajorStep`  property of the axis for the purpose.

For example, from Xaml

```
<oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" MajorStep="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
</oxy:Plot.Axes>
```

Or from ViewModel

```
 var yAxis = new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                Maximum = 100,
                Minimum = 0,
                MajorStep = 5
            };
```

You could additionally set `MinorStep="5"` (same value as MajorStep) if you would like to the Minor Ticks as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem. The axis has to be auto-scaled so MajorStep also needs to be changed by OxyPlot. If I set MajorStep = 1 when the axis range is 0..1000 (for example) the result is just silly. That's precisely why I need the MinimumMajorStep property.